# Create customized SliverPersistentHeader like Widget with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Header that consists of:

1 - appBar (title + return button)
2 - row with a data picker)
3 - a row serving as a customized TabBar (with two Tabs)
4 - a row serving as a FilterBar (with a Button and a search field)

Then I have the "body" with a list of Cards that is scrollable.

I needed to retract/hide numbers 1-3 and keep only number 4 visible when I scroll down the list of cards. How could I build a customized Widget to help me with that?

Here is part of the code (it's too long to bring everything):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          title: 'List of Tasks',
          elevation: 0.0,
          pinned: true,
        ),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: DatePicker(
              date: date,
              onChange: (newDate) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: ActivitiesTabController(
            pageController: _pageController,
            currentTab: currentTab,
            onChangedTab: (currentTab) {},
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SearchFilterBar(
                taskId: taskId,
                onChange: (floors, serviceName) {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Container(color: Colors.amberAccent, height: 150.0);
          }),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Please add the code you already have.

Comment: Thanks Akif. I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to two app bars, where the first one can be scrolled away while the second one is persistent.

I think it would be something like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('This hides'),
      ),
      SliverAppBar(
        title: Text('This is always shown'),
        pinned: true,
        primary: false,
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (_, i) {
            return ListTile(title: Text('Line $i'));
          },
          childCount: 150,
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex. It's very close to that. The only thing is that the last Row (before the list of cards) - the one that needs to stay, is not an AppBar. It's a Row with a Button and a searchbox). I'm posting some of the code on my original question to help it out.